# Angular component "mat-tree" or "tree" access to windows filesystem

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Angular 8 and i want to get access to localhost windows filesystem and bind it to the tree.

Think something like the "Navigation Pane" in Windows explorer.

Thank you

Comment: You can't reach local file system from angular. Browser applications are not allowed to reach local file path due to security reasons. Only way is file input.

Comment: also there is security walls to get file input path

Comment: Also is there any way to alter the browser settings for localhost access?

Comment: I don't think so. This leads to big security problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd way

1. Make a local web server with this tool https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome
2. Choose the folder you want
3. Choose the port etc
4. Then Install Local CORS Proxy
5. npm install -g local-cors-proxy
6. then proxy the webservered port
7. lcp --proxyUrl https://127.0.0.1:####/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Browsers forbidden root access to file-system,
the way i did it, is make a python api that construct a json from the file-system and call it from angular